# How to open My static/single websites Demos from React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and have built a react portfolio website to show some of my samples and demos,
each of my demos has a folder which contains `index.html`, `style.css` and `function.js`.

On my react app I have a box(div) for each demo and I want to redirect or open index.html of the demo when I click on the box.

I have been searching and trying a lot of stuff but none of them solved my problem.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Link' component from routing to render appropriate views/pages.

```
<Link to="/specify/path/here">Go to demo</Link>
```

You can check out my detailed article on routing in react
[here](https://medium.com/@prajwalkulkarni76/a-definitive-guide-to-react-routing-cf024697436e)

Answer (score 0):

i find it out: i can put my demos inside Public folder and use

```
<a href="/demo-folder-name/index.html" />
```

and it will work .